# React Components Library + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I want to create a java-script library file that contains a few React components I composed and I used "create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts" command with npm to create the project ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter)).

I want to pack/bundle this project (Webpack) without having any html file.. only components so I can take the output js file, include it in another project and use its components.

I tried looking for some Webpack configuration but all I find is not sutiable for TypeScript project.

**Can you help me configuring Webpack?**

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you need webpack for this. You are creating modules to be included, and webpack only enters the picture when it comes to deploying the final app.

Comment: the html file generated by running `npm build` with your setup is useless, what metters is the .js files created alogside it. You can insert them anywhere you want.